# What is the maximum size of azure easy tables?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I searched on the internet and not found any answer related to it.
Could someone tell what is the maximum size of data we can accommodate with azure easy tables? 
What is the maximum size we can have a backup of?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using the Azure Easy Table, we need to configure the connections of Azure SQL and Azure Storage. The data of Azure Easy Table will be stored in Azure SQL database and Azure Storage.

> Could someone tell what is the maximum size of data we can accommodate with azure easy tables?

So the maximum size of data we can accommodate with azure easy tables depends on the Azure SQL database which you choose.

Comment: Thanks Amor,
Does this same apply to taking backup of data?

Comment: Yes, to backup the data, you need to backup the data stored in Azure SQL and Azure Storage.

Comment: Thanks Amor, Marking Answer.